# Can't make Laravel change database when running tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing

First, my problem started when I noticed that when I used `RefreshDatabase` trait in test. It migrated my whole dev database, purging everything! I don't know if that's the way it works, but I need my database to run my app locally and hand-test it.

Then I tried using `sqlite` only for tests. First, I added this line to `phpunit.xml`

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

But it did not work. Running tests still refreshed `mysql` database.

Then I tried adding a `.env.testing` file, and changing `DB_CONNECTION` to `sqlite`.

It did not work again.

Then I added this line to `setUp` in one test:

```
dd(env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), config('database.default'));
```

Result when having database in `phpunit.xml`:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

"sqlite"
"mysql"
```

Result when having `.env.testing`:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

"mysql"
"mysql"
```

I there anything I can try to find out why this happens?

Laravel: Laravel Framework 5.8.35

PHP: PHP 7.3.7

Comment: Are you sure `.env.testing` is being loaded instead of `.env`?

Comment: Check PHPunit is using `phpunit.xml`

Comment: @tanerkay How can I make sure of it? Docs say it should load it.

Comment: @GörkemD. How can I check if it is being loaded?

Comment: `phpunit --configuration filelocation` if it is work check your phpunit location

Comment: Thanks @GörkemD., read my answer. I tried phpunit with and without `--configuration`. It works now, so I really don't know what was my problem.

Comment: @vfsoraki Ok if i wrote an answer will you apply? Maybe I could find a solution.

Comment: @GörkemD. Sure. Let's see what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`phpunit --configuration filelocation`

If it works, Go to basepath and execute `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` and `phpunit.xml` must be at basepath.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What a mess!

After searching *a lot* I found someone suggested `php artisan config:cache --env=testing` and it did work!

But after that, my application was using testing environment totally!

Then I tried `php artisan config:clear` and it worked!

My problem is solved, but what a mess it is. I still will accept another answer if anyone can provide an explanation or a nice solution.

Comment: It's because you must have cached the config at some point and your tests were using the cache that contained your production env. The first command works because you are caching the testing env instead, but this is obviously not ideal because you don't want to use your testing env in production. It's probably best to avoid caching your config locally, or you could always clear your cache automatically in your test set up.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a new previously unused variable in `.env.testing` would test whether it is being used, or if another and/or cached config is used instead.

The problem would be that you are using your dev environment for both development and testing, so once one `.env` file is cached, `bootstrap/cache/config.php` is set until you clear the config cache.

The solution would be to isolate the working copy used for testing.

In reality, not every project is set up ideally with Docker containers or VMs for each environment, or sometimes you just want to quickly initiate your tests

If you want to use the same working copy for both, I'd recommended you do not cache routes or config.

Answer (score 0):

try

> php artisan config:clear

this will prevent laravel to cache configuration, phpunit.xml can rewrite .env soo